# How to select elements under "dl", "dd" html tags for webscaping (bs4)

Tags: python, html, css, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape the site **'stockx'** to get the information at the bottom under the 12 month historical section, for some reason I can get some elements such as the `last_sale` price, but I can't get any of the elements at the bottom such as volatility, I get an error for the volatility no matter what I try to do.

This is the html, I want to get the part that says `2%`

```
<dl>
 <dt class="chakra-stat__label css-1qtnkr4">Volatility
  </dt>
 <dd class="chakra-stat__number css-jcr674">2%</dd>
</dl>
```

this is my code, currently volatility returns an error but `last_sale` works just fine.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:80.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/80.0',
    'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.5'
}

cookies = {
    'stockx_homepage': "sneakers",
}

def main(url):
    r = requests.get(url, headers=headers, cookies=cookies)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'lxml')
    last_sale = soup.select('.css-xfmxd4')[0]
    volatility = soup.find("dd",class_="chakra-stat__number .css-jcr674")

    print("last sale: " + last_sale.text + "\n")
    print("volatility: " + volatility.text + "\n")

url = https://stockx.com/adidas-yeezy-boost-350-turtle-dove-2022?-size=11
main(url)
```

please help, I don't know why I cant select/find the `'dd' tag`, or the particular `css` for that part

Answer (score 0):

try this

> `volatility=soup.find("dd",{"class":"chakra-stat__number css-jcr674"}).text`

Comment: It still wont work, I get this error "AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'"

Answer (score 0):

I found the website I was trying to scrape is javascript dynamic thus i had to implement selenium chromedriver to get data loaded in javascript